# In my Visual Studio 2019 I dont have a "Git"

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019

this question is super trivial but I'm very new to programming. Just watched a 5:27 tutorial for using Git in VS2019, (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/git-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) but unlike in the video i dont have a "Git" option between "View" and "Project" on the toolbar at the top of my VS. Does anyone know how to add "Git" to there?

Comment: One person had similar issue, take a look: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/visual-studio-2019-166-no-git-menu/1050505

Comment: @LukeHutton Thank you, that is it

Comment: np, happy learning!

Comment: @KrzysiekDymanowski here's a good chance to get some karma - write an answer that serves as standalone (i.e. not just redirect to the link posted in comments, which might stop working in future) - you can cite it as source